# C# MVC5 EF6 data initializer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have two simple related tables - question and answer.

```
    public class Question
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Ask { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

I have an initializer which creates 2 questions

```
var questions = new List<Question>
{
    new Question {Header="Attending Meeting:", Ask="Did you attend the meeting:", QuestionID=0 },
    new Question {Header="Overall:",Ask="Was the meeting:", QuestionID=1}
};
```

with an answer set for question 0 thus.

```
var answers = new List<Answer>
{
    new Answer {Text="No",Value="-1",AnswerID=0,QuestionID=0,DisplayOrder=1 },
    new Answer {Text="Yes",Value="0",AnswerID=1,QuestionID=0,DisplayOrder=2}
}
```

Now I always want question 0 ("did you attend") to have a specific ID so I can test for it (if you didn't attend the meeting then no further questions) which I have arbitrarily set at 0.  If I try and run the initializer then the answers give me a value for the QuestionID of 1 as the QuestionID field of the Question table has the identity value set thus:

```
[QuestionID]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
```

Now I know that I can switch the auto-increment off permanently using fluent but that would make other things harder...  Is there any way in the initialiser that I can do the equivalent of SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF and then turn it back on afterwards?

All of the examples I have seen work using the position of the relative data in the collections to ensure that values run from 1,2,3... and the foreign keys rely on this sequence.

Comment: That smells. Why not just add an attribute to Question like "IsAttendedQuestion" or if you have a number of questions you need to test for add an enum or another table. I'd much rather read code that says if (currentQuestion.IsAttendedQuestion) { ... } than if (currentQuestion.QuestionId == 0) { ... }

Comment: It's certainly a view point.  But this is going to be the only exception and adding a whole new field for a single value in a single question which is a very specific process also smells.   But that is a matter of opinion.  To be frank, not having some form of identity insert smells to me.

Comment: Then don't use a surrogate key (identity). Once you start caring about the value of the Id you should use a natural key.

Comment: OK - thanks for your views.  Can you assist me with the query with regard to the original problem?